# How to write the English "sh" ⟨ʃ⟩ in Japanese?

Tags: translation, katakana, names

I've learned that if you're translating a name into Japanese you have to translate it by the sound.
I want to translate the name "Tymoteusz". I think the name itself is Greek but the writing is Polish, however it's not Japanese so I need katakana.
I started translating.

The first sound is a "t" and then "y" (you read the "y" in polish [⟨ɘ⟩](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_central_unrounded_vowel)). There is no sound in Japanese that sounds like this so I used チ.

Then the next sounds are pretty easy. First just a モ.
Then テ.
And then ウ.

So I got チモテウ. Now I need the last sound. You read "sz" like a English "sh" ([⟨ʃ⟩](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_postalveolar_fricative#Voiceless_palato-alveolar_fricative)). I've heard Japanese People using this soind, but I have no Idea how to write it. Can someone help me?

How to write [⟨ʃ⟩](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_postalveolar_fricative#Voiceless_palato-alveolar_fricative) in Japanese?
And is my translation correct (all sounds without IPA sound like the Japanese ones)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the lone-standing [ʃ] tends to be represented, as it is the case with most of the consonants, with the U vowel: thus, I'd expect it to be rendered as シュ.

Luckily, we can check that: by putting "Tymoteusz" into the Japanese Wikipedia search, we can learn whether there are precedents and how famous people with that name are rendered. On [this](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%99%E3%82%A2%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B7%E3%83%89%E3%82%A5%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A9) page, for example, I find it written as 「ティモテウシュ」, as expected.

By the way, while it is true that native (and Sino-Japanese) words do not contain a separate from チ, most Japanese have no problem with pronouncing it, and there is a standardized way of writing it: ティ. (Of course, the vowel is not an exact match, but it is specifically rendered to Japanese as [i]: [like here](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%B4%E3%83%AF%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%AF%E3%83%952%E4%B8%96_(%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E7%8E%8B)).)

So, ティモテウシュ is the answer.